# Setting two objects using LinearLayout in Android

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to create a simple layout in Android. Basically my big rectangle is supposed to be centered horizontally and vertically. The small button is positioned vertically between bottom of the screen and center of the screen in equal distance and horizontally centered.
[image: reference]

Big rectangle's dimensions are 354 × 168
Small rectangle's dimensions are 124x48

Should I use a linear layout or relative layout? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#000" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1" >
         <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#000" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Aakash, I had a similar layout but I didn't use the second RelativeLayout. However my problem is my image is scaling up even when I set width and height. Is this normal?

Comment: I set them in 'pt' instead of 'dp' could that be the problem?

Comment: dp is preferred as it adjusts according to different screen sizes

Comment: I managed to solve the  pt->dp issue but unfortunately small button still not centered.  Is there a way to position it 3/4 of the screen independent from the big rect?

Comment: because big button's position is .5 of the total height of the screen, small button's position is .75 of the screen considering top left is 0,0

Comment: post your xml and i will check it out

Comment: I am using exactly what you posted above.

Comment: instead of giving center in parent to second button, align it center horizontally and give marginTop to it